# Selecting column and max

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'll explain my problem so it becomes clearer.

I have to select the hospital with the biggest amount of medics.

My table looks like this :

```
Medic_Hospital values (codhospital,codmedic)
```

I have tried :

```
SELECT MAX(codmedic) FROM Medic_Hospital
```

but that only returns the number 6 
( which is one of the medic's id )

```
SELECT codhospital,count(codmedic) FROM Medic_Hospital
where max(codmedic) = count(codmedic)
group by codhospital
```

but this also failed as

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
SELECT codhospital,MAX(COUNT(codmedic)) from Medic_Hospital
```

but that failed as

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery."

I'm not very experienced in SQL and I can see that my logic is failing me here. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `top` clause to return just the first row of an ordered query:

```
SELECT   TOP 1 codhospital, COUNT(codmedic) 
FROM     Medic_Hospital
GROUP BY codhospital
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: It worked but I didn't understant that 2 , would you mind explaining ? It was such a no brainer !

Also would you mind providing an example without `TOP` ? I don't know if I'll be allowed to use it

Comment: @Onilol it's an ordinal notation - sort by (`order by`) the second column (`2`) in descending order (`desc`)

Comment: You mind providing another example without `TOP` please ?

Comment: @Onilol the usage of `top` is the base for this answer, so I'm not quite sure what you're asking (or perhaps I'm just being dense) - could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Is there any other way you could do it without using `top` ?

Comment: @Onilol possibly with the window functions such as `rank`, but that would be cumbersome as heck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97569/discussion-between-onilol-and-mureinik).